# Get result from Google Map and transfer data back to previous fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have created a Google Map feature for my android app. When the user Goes on FragmentA they are asked to input some information such as name and description of a Job. When they get lower down on that page they can select a Map button that allows them to open a Google Map that I have created. On this fragment, FragmentMap, they can select a location. Once they are happy they can press a green tick/check icon that displays a PopUp asking if they are happy with the location.

When the user selects the Yes button I want the address that they have selected from the map, to be transferred from FragmentMap back to FragmentA. I also need FragmentA to retain all of the users information that they had already entered before pressing the Map button.

For Example, the user has entered A Job Name, Description and Collection Date and they then press the map. They then choose a location on the map and confirm it is correct. Then they will go back to FragmentA where all of the details previously entered are still in the EditText fields as well as the addres from the Map that the user has selected.

**FragmentA, Where the user can input data, such as Avdert Name. When they press the Map Button they will be Displayed with FragmentMap**

[image: FragmentA]

**Once the user has chosen a location and confirmed it they will be displayed with this PopUp. If they press yes the Address, as shown, will be transferred back to FragmentA**

[image: Confirming Location]

My Question is, how can I transfer data from my Map fragment back to FragmentA and retain all previous data that was in FragmentA. I was thinking about using a bundle to transfer data from FragmentA to FragmentMap and then pass it back again. Is their a more efficient and easy way?

**Note**

My question is different to others that i have found as its about a map and retaing information from the previous fragment

Answer (score 1):

You may call setTargetFragment() when you start the Fragment B from A. Example:

```
FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance();
fragmentB.setTargetFragment(FragmentA.this, REQUEST_CODE);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, 
fragmentB).commit();
```

and then when you want to pass data back to fragment A from B, you can call the following code:

```
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
            getTargetRequestCode(),
            Activity.RESULT_OK,
            new Intent().putExtra("datafrom B", "datafrom B")
);
```

And get it from the onActivityResult() method in your fragment A:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    String datafromB = data.getStringExtra("datafrom B");   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass you information to the Activity that contains both the fragments like `((MainActivity)getActivity()).mapLocationUpdated(latlng)` and create the `mapLocationUpdated` in your activity, then pass the information to the previous fragment by finding the fragment(with `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag)` and passing it the info.

You can also create an interface that the activity implements (like `MapLocationInteractor` that has the method `mapLocationUpdated(latlng)` and call your activity like this : `((MapLocationInteractor)getActivity()).mapLocationUpdated(latlng)`.

Don't forget to check for nulls in the getActivity and findFragment parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by creating the method in particular fragment and pass the instance of google map